# How to debug EXC_BAD_ACCESS in iPhone app when I can't determine the cause?

Tags: iphone, debugging, exc-bad-access

Help, I've been hacking at this for weeks now! I have this app I am developing in the Simulator, and I have done a lot of the UI stuff, it is just getting to the interesting part with data. It started immediately upon launch, about 90% of the time I run it, it will raise EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.

I have commented out all of my release messages, and even added some retain messages to be sure it is not something that is over released. Weird thing is, sometimes something I do in the code will make it work, then it works until I make another code change. Then I comment out the new code I added, and it still crashes.

I have read through probably a dozen articles on the web on this, tried the things they suggest. I have set breakpoints, and still can't figure out where it is. When I click up the call stack in the debugger, the only place that shows source code is the bottom level which is main.

The debugger has this stack, but that fluctuates a bit each time it crashes. The inconsistent nature tells me there is some memory it is autoreleasing, but I have no idea how to find out what.

```
0 objc_msgSend
1 ??
2 _CFAutoReleasePoolPop
3 -[NSAutoReleasePool release]
4 _UIApplicationHandleEvent
5 PurpleEventCallback
6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1
8 __CFRunLoopRun
9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
10 CFRunLoopRunInMode
11 -[UIApplication _run]
12 UIApplicationMain
13 main
```

A few more facts:

- I set NSZombieEnabled, that didn't
  make a difference in the console
  output
- I ran Instruments using the
  Leaks profile, it didn't show any
  leaks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you will want to enable zombie objects in your code, and Checking Autoreleased objects, and perhaps enabling debugging will help.

I added three Environment Variables.

- NSZombieEnabled
- NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled
- NSDebugEnabled

all of these are set to YES

here is a link with the path I took.

http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone

if you are using XCode 4 then you will add these in the Arguments section of the Edit Schemes popover.

Another thing to note is, you should only release or autorelease objects that you are retaining. You maintain a retain on the following objects.

- Any object you alloc [NSObject alloc]
- Any object obtained using the static new command [NSObject new]
- Any object you explicitly retain [myObject retain]
- Any copy of an object [myObject copy]
- Any property with the retain or copy attribute @property (retain) NSString *myProperty;

if you send an autorelease to any object other than these, you could randomly end up with this and other errors.

commonly I release objects and then set them to nil, that way if i release them later, I wont have any issue because if you autorelease nil, you get nil.

```
NSObject *myObject = [incomingObject retain];
// Do something with the object.
[myObject autorelease];
[myObject autorelease]; // This line will end in an error down the line when the object is released past 0, or when the release pool is drained.
myObject = nil;
[myObject release]; // This line will do nothing. no error, no effect.
```

Comment: Thanks, Jason.  I assume you mean NSZombieEnabled?  Didn't make a difference in the console output.  I added to the executable the NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled=YES variable, didn't make a difference in console either.  What am I looking for with that?

Comment: I was having the same issues you are, I looked all over cause the stack track was not helpful. I ended up with three environment variables. (NSZombieEnabled, NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled, NSDebugEnabled) maybe the last one is helpful... Also there are only a few objects you should ever release. I will update the Post to include them.

Comment: I found those variables in Debug.h, but setting them on the executable inspector, and restarting the simulator didn't seem to make a difference.  This has got to be solvable.  I do have one autorelease in a tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: on the view it generates for the cell, but removing the autorelease message didn't prevent the crash.

Comment: so you are saying that you have no autorelease calls save for the one in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Correct, it's a mystery!  (btw I am using XCode 3, I'm downloading 4 but I don't know if it will make a diff)  Now what I could do is overhaul all of my functions, do a retain in the beginning of the function on passed-in pointers, and release at the end, see if that helps.  Maybe do one function at a time, see if I can narrow it down.

Comment: how do you get the cell that you are auto releasing.

Comment: I wonder if perhaps it could be a mistyped variable/property, like I left out the * to make it a pointer?  I won't have a chance to look at the code again until next week.

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
 [cell retain];

Comment: Interestingly enough, I tried the build in XCode 4.  Now the app does not crash immediately upon launch - the first tab's viewcontroller is displayed, but as soon as I tap on another tab I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS, and the source code highlights the main app entry point in main.m

Comment: Never mind @Jason!!  Found the problem. First, I installed XCode 4, and let me say this is WAY better!  I ran Instruments straight from XCode with Zombie profile, and it showed the bad access right away, the module in which it occurred, and when I double-click the line, it took me directly to the line in source code.  Awesome!  The problem, I was getting the Documents path, and thought since I had allocated it that I needed to release it, didn't know it was automatically added to the Autorelease pool.  Below is the offending code:

Comment: `NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
              NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
...
[path release]; //<<-- this caused the problem`

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is adding a garbage or already freed object to the Autorelease pool - maybe in that `PurpleEventCallback` function?

Comment: How do I add an object to the autorelease pool, is that by sending a release message?  I commented out all of my release messages in the entire app to make sure it wasn't overreleasing.

Comment: that is a good way to start a leak. and release is not normally the culprit, unless you start with an autoreleased object.. try counting the retains and releases on the objects you have. make sure they match.

Comment: All of the retains I have are assignments to retain properties.  I tried adding a few retains to ensure life beyond the function, but since they did not make the error go away I removed them.  Forgive me, I'm new to iPhone/mac development, but if I assign to a retain property, the release occurs when that object is dealloced, right?  I should add, the crash occurs right away in the app, after the tab bar views/nav controllers are initialized, and before you can tap anything.  I don't know what I did to introduce it.

Comment: release objects that are in retained properties in the -(void) dealloc {} method.

Comment: Great to know, thanks!  But, if I don't release them in dealloc, that would cause a leak, but it would not cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS, right?

Comment: BTW, Paul, that PurpleEventCallback function is some internal function, no idea what it does.  Something in the app life cycle.  The only item in the call stack that shows source code is the bottom one, which is the app main.