# AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv Crash log from TestFlight, what does it mean?

Tags: ios, iphone-5, crash-reports, xcode4.6, testflight

I received a crash log from TestFlight, after I've uploaded the dsym file, the crash log is as shown below.

Unfortunately I am clueless what it means, and how I can find the cause of this crash. Am I missing something here?

```
SIGSEGV
libobjc.A.dylib_ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv

Occurrences1
Users1
#   Binary Image Name   Address Symbol
0   Moon Stones 0x0004d71e  testflight_backtrace
1   Moon Stones 0x0004cdb6  TFSignalHandler
2   libsystem_c.dylib   0x393eed3a  _sigtramp
3   libobjc.A.dylib 0x38f77494  _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv
4   CoreFoundation  0x311c2830  _CFAutoreleasePoolPop
5   Foundation  0x31ae8604  -[NSAutoreleasePool release]
6   UIKit   0x3308e572  _UIApplicationHandleEvent
7   GraphicsServices    0x34da65f6  _PurpleEventCallback
8   GraphicsServices    0x34da6226  PurpleEventCallback
9   CoreFoundation  0x312543e6  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
10  CoreFoundation  0x3125438a  __CFRunLoopDoSource1
11  CoreFoundation  0x3125320e  __CFRunLoopRun
12  CoreFoundation  0x311c623c  CFRunLoopRunSpecific
13  CoreFoundation  0x311c60c8  CFRunLoopRunInMode
14  GraphicsServices    0x34da533a  GSEventRunModal
15  UIKit   0x330e22b8  UIApplicationMain
16  Moon Stones 0x0000e73a  main in main.m on Line 16
17  Moon Stones 0x0000951f  start
```

Crashed occurred at # `3    libobjc.A.dylib 0x38f77494  _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv`

I would be probably adding TFLogs for logging, and adding checkpoints to get a clue for future crashes.

Any help and insight on this crash log will be appreciated.

Edit: Attached screenshot.
[image]

Comment: are you using ARC or manually releasing your memory?

Comment: Yes I am using ARC, however I have some classes that are not. Reason: Objective c++ .mm files.

Comment: Do you have the crash report that iOS generated?

Comment: It looks like this is a problem with the autorelease pool, which could hint at a bad memory management where an object gets released one time more and then a SIGSEGV happens. If you're using ARC, you can focus only on the .mm files so that the problem can be solved faster

Comment: @Kerni I don't have it now, the crash was from a tester. I'll ask him for a log.

Comment: This any use? http://bhapca.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/how-to-deal-with-excbadaccess-triggered.html

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656842/how-to-debug-exc-bad-access-in-iphone-app-when-i-cant-determine-the-cause

Comment: @Mike I'm not sure if this has to do with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. You get then trying to access deallocated or nil objects. From the other comments, mine could be a case of over-releasing, though I'm still figuring it out. Thanks for the advice though. =)

Answer (score -1):

it seems that you are using third party library & this crash occur there while you performing any type of Navigation or adding subviews or removing subviews.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I was reading, is there a way I can bring this crash log into my xcode and symbolicate the crash? Or was it symbolicated already, since I've uploaded the dsym file?

Comment: Frames? sorry I do not understand, perhaps I'll provide a screenshot on my question.

Comment: @justinkoh: This log is already symbolicated and is in a custom format with custom data. Xcode can only process standard formatted crash reports.

Comment: That was a question to @Karam and asking how he comes to his conclusion because the crash report doesn't show much or rather doesn't show anything as specific as he says.

Comment: `Foundation` is not a third party library. Also what indicates that the crash occurs when adding/removing subviews?

Comment: As per the crash log its not clear that where actually its happen because its a symbolicated but its states that UIKit is about to handle an event & while its going to take over the event then that controller is out of pool   `5  Foundation  0x31ae8604  -[NSAutoreleasePool release]
6   UIKit   0x3308e572  _UIApplicationHandleEvent.` So as he is using some c++ & other third party libraries for their code. And he is also using ARC for his project but some of the classes are not compatible of ARC. So as per experience I give him the answer/suggestion.

Comment: 1. You claim that it is not clear because the report is symbolicated. Symbolication means resolving memory addresses into their corresponding function name. So symbolication does make it MORE clear! 2. The event your are talking about does not have to be a user interaction! 3. `That controller is out of pool` does not make any sense.